# Unwrap mesh to plane while maintaining quad dimensions and angles

Tags: mesh, faces

I am designing a yacht in Blender to construct in plywood. This means that the shapes I create need to be cut from flat stock and bent into shape. There is (expensive) ship design software that can develop the plates from a 3d model. So it can be done. I just can't figure a way to do it in Blender.

What is essential is that the quads not get distorted in any way during the process. Mesh --> cleanup --> Flatten; Loop tools-->Flatten both distort the quads.

I've attempted it manually by triangulating the quads, using normal orientations, calculating angles to rotate etc. etc. I've even tried softbody with max stiffness as well as scanned all the responses to related questions here and elsewhere. I'm enjoying this greatly as an exercise in exploring Blender's capabilities as a marine cad tool, but it's time I called for a little help.[image: Side panel]

Comment: UV unwrap was not made for his sort of work, it *will* invariably introduce distortions, if not by nature because not all meshes are unwrapable.

Comment: Thanks, but "unwrap" was an unfortunate term to use. I haven't tried the UV unwrap feature for the reason you mention but I do need to "unwrap" from it's curve in the model onto a flat plane without distorting the edge length or quad angles.

Comment: Hum, I see, have you tried looking into papercraft addons? Not sure if there are any for Blender, but they may fill the same requirements you need.

Comment: Quick Google search yielded this https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Import-Export/Paper_Model

Comment: Thanks again. I have actually used that program to make a model of the yacht and poked around in the "guts" of it for clues. From memory (it was a couple of years ago now) my conclusion was that the process was just a bit too slack for transferring to the real world of constructing an actual boat.

edit: Just found it - "# warning: this constructor modifies its parameter (face)"

Comment: This software may be of interest to you, just learned it from other user question http://www.touchcad.com/